# Inline sound effect using command line

Tags: shell, audio, software-rec

I found a while ago a way to modify recorded sound (pitch and such) and playing it through speaker in a single command line, involving "rec", piped to another command...
But silly me, I didn't save it for later use...

Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`sox`](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) — the Swiss Army knife of audio manipulation — is a program that can apply effects to audio.

It usually takes as parameter one or more input files, an output file, and the effects to apply. It can also be invoked as `rec` or `play`, and then it uses the default sound device as input or output, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

If you have pulseaudio then you have the commands `parec` and `pacat` at your disposal for recording and play back. The option `--rate` of `pacat` allows you to change pitch.